# React: What is the naming convention to inform the return type of the function is jsx in the comments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, comments

I believe most of the developers follow guidelines rolled out by JSDocs for commenting in JavaScript. So, this is how I usually provide comments for the function I create to help other developers who might work on the same file:

```
  /**
   * Renders the translated section in sidebar.
   *
   * @param {array} langList - List of languages to be rendered
   * @param {boolean} isTranslated - If true render translations
   * @return {JSX} - Returns JSX
   */
  _renderLangSection (langList, isTranslated) {
    return (
      <div>{isTranslated ? langlist : null}</div>
    );
  }
```

As you can see the return type of this function is JSX. Is this the right return type? Or is **React element** a better name? Does anyone know what the React community prefers?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you call the return type to be JSX as after this function gets compiled with Babel, the JSX code gets transformed to pure javascript as

```
function _renderLangSection (langList, isTranslated) {
  return React.createElement("div", null, isTranslated ? langlist : null);
}
```

which ultimately returns a React element.

Answer (score 0):

The Flow type of the return value is `React.Node`, as shown by the tooltip overlay in VSCode.